# draggable d3 world globe in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have the next problem I'm trying to create a draggable world globe with d3 in a svelte app, the problem that i have is when a try to drag the globe the drag action is laggy I think that my problem have someting to do with a memory leak in the draggable component I don't know if this is the main reason of this laggy behaviour. The globe was drew with svg's

This is the App link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-benz-2mk5bs

**Draggable component**

```
<script>
    import { onMount, onDestroy, afterUpdate } from 'svelte';

    import { mouseAdjusted } from '../lib/Utilities';

    onMount(() => console.log('mounted'));

    afterUpdate(() => {
        //console.log('Destroyed');
    });

    export let mouseX;
    export let mouseY;
    let offset;

    let isMove = false;
    const start = (e) => {
        isMove = true;
        const element = e.target;
        const target = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getScreenCTM();

        // get the mouse position in the svg shape
        offset = mouseAdjusted(e.clientX, e.clientY, target);
        // rest the shape mouse posicion from the shape x y coordinates
        offset[1] -= +element.getAttributeNS(null, 'y');
        offset[0] -= +element.getAttributeNS(null, 'x');
    };
    const move = (e) => {
        if (isMove) {
            const target = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getScreenCTM();
            const [x, y] = mouseAdjusted(e.clientX, e.clientY, target);
            mouseX = offset[0] - x;
            mouseY = offset[1] - y;
        }
    };
    const end = () => {
        isMove = false;
        offset = null;
    };
</script>

<svelte:window
    on:mousemove|preventDefault|stopPropagation={move}
    on:mouseup|preventDefault|stopPropagation={end}
/>
<g class="draggable" on:mousedown|preventDefault|stopPropagation={start}>
    <slot />
</g>
```

**Graph component**

```
<script>
    import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";
    import * as d3 from "d3";
    import * as topojson from "topojson-client";
    import Draggable from "./draggable.svelte";

    let width = 500;
    $: width = width * 0.95;
    let height = 500;
    $: height = height * 0.98;
    let world;
    let x;
    let y;
    let projection;
    let path;
    let ROTATION = [-45, -65, 0];
    // Add topojsom
    onMount(async () => {
      const resp = await d3.json(
        "/src/assets/world-administrative-boundaries.json"
      );
      world = await topojson.feature(resp, "world-administrative-boundaries");
    });

    $: ROTATION = [-x, y, 0];
    $: projection = d3
      .geoOrthographic()
      .fitSize([width, height], world)
      .scale([width / 3])
      .rotate(ROTATION);

    $: path = d3.geoPath(projection);

    const fillScale = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(["", ""])
      .range([" hsl(40, 98%, 47%)", "hsl(9, 64%, 50%)"])
      .unknown("hsl(227, 16%, 42%)");
    const strokeScale = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(["", ""])
      .range([" hsl(40, 98%, 35%)", "hsl(9, 64%, 35%)"])
      .unknown("hsl(227, 16%, 22%)");
    // transform to features
    $: countries = world?.features.map(obj => {
      const { geometry, properties, _ } = obj;
      //const d = path(geometry);
      const fill = fillScale(properties.iso3);
      const stroke = strokeScale(properties.iso3);
      const newProperties = Object.assign({ ...properties }, { fill, stroke });
      return Object.assign({}, { geometry, properties: newProperties });
    });

    //  $: console.log('features', features);
    //$: console.log('first', ROTATION);
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth={width} bind:innerHeight={height} />

<svg {width} {height}>
    <Draggable bind:mouseX={x} bind:mouseY={y}>
        {#if countries}
            <path class="sphere" d={path({ type: 'Sphere' })} />
            <g class="countries">
                {#each countries as country}
                    <path
                        d={path(country.geometry)}
                        fill={country.properties.fill}
                        stroke={country.properties.stroke}
                        
                    />
                {/each}
            </g>
        {/if}
    </Draggable>
</svg>

<!-- markup (zero or more items) goes here -->
<style>
    svg {
      border: 1px solid tomato;
    }

    .sphere {
      fill: var(--base-color-2);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: iirc D3 has mouse(x,y) conversions to ie geoOrthographic ... I cannot edit your example wanted to try ie`x/3` ... and I was wondering whether you should bind mouse in D3 context and not in SVG? See ie https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=d3+mouse+drag+world

Comment: Is there a way to edit the app without having to create an account on codesandbox?